# An analytical derivation to decide whether a certain asset should be decided to my portfolio?

Tags: finance, covariance, correlation

## Question

- I found a simplified inequation to decide whether the new asset A should be added to my current portfolio B. If the following inequation is satisfied, the new asset A should be added to my portfolio. (source: Mackenzie Investment's research report [Correlation vs. Beta: What is the difference](https://www.mackenzieinvestments.com/content/dam/final/corporate/mackenzie/docs/investment-teams/multi-asset-team/en/Correlation%20vs.%20Beta_%20What%20is%20The%20Difference%20and%20Why%20Does%20It%20Matter_%20_%20Mackenzie%20Investments.pdf))

$$\frac{E(R_{a})}{\sigma_{a}} > \frac{E(R_{b})}{\sigma_{b}} \times corr(R_{a}, R_{b})$$

- One colleague of mine suggested to me that the inequation shown above seems to be derived from the mathematical equation written below, when the condition $W_{a}> 0$ is satisfied.

[image]

- $W_{a}$: how much percentage of my total wealth is invested in the asset A 
  $E(R_{a})$: the expected return of the asset A 
  $\sigma_{a}$: the standard deviation of the returns of the asset A
  $r_{f}$: risk-free return such as the US government bonds
  *I assume that $R_{A}$ is the same thing as $R_{a}$, which means the return of the asset A*.
- Is there anyone who can show me how the equation written at the bottom can be simplified to the inequation written at the top, when the condition $W_{a}> 0$ is satisfied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has another origin. Consider the linear model:
$$r_{A}=\beta_{r_p,r_A}r_p+\varepsilon=\frac{\textrm{Cov}(r_A,r_p)}{\sigma_{r_p}^2}r_p+\varepsilon$$
where $E[\varepsilon]=0$ and the error is independent of $r_p$. The expected return of asset $A$ is then $E[r_A]=\beta_{r_p,r_a}E[r_p]$. The rule states that if the return/volatility ratio (sort of Sharpe ratio) of the actual expected return of asset $A$ is greater than the model's, then you should add the asset to the portfolio:
$$\frac{E[r_p]\rho_{A,p}}{\sigma_{r_p}}=\frac{E[r_p]\textrm{Cov}(r_A,r_p)}{\sigma_{r_p}^2\sigma_{r_A}}=\frac{E[r_{p}]\beta_{r_p,r_A}}{\sigma_{r_A}}<\frac{E[r_A]}{\sigma_{r_A}}$$